# How to smooth move an object with GPS coords

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gps, augmented-reality

i want to use android GPS coords to make a camera motion in unity

i have made a ar game that use Gyro as camera rotation an now what i want is to walk around unity virtual world, i know that GPS coords is degrees then should not work as is, however, someone know a formula to make its work? ive downloaded this plugin but they convert a littlest decimal degrees to a thousand "meters"

https://github.com/MichaelTaylor3D/UnityGPSConverter/blob/master/GPSEncoder.cs

Comment: At the equator one degree is 40,000,000 m / 360 = 111,111 m. So, if you want a meter precision, you must provide the GPS as precise as by 0.000009 degree. Also, `float` with about 7 decimal digits precision is at its limits here.

Comment: GPS is (currently) accurate to a few meters, which is impressive given that the satellites it's triangulating from are ~20 million meters away.  you could use something like ARCore to get a better estimate of where a device is in a world